# Facebook ads API daily_budget update limitations

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to update ads with daily budgets. From FB API we learn that:

> When updating a set's lifetime or daily budget to a lower value, the new value must be at least 10% greater than the current amount spent already. For example: if an ad set has a $1000 lifetime budget and has spend $300 so far, the lowest new lifetime budget would be $330.

Does this rule mean that if we want to update the daily budget of an Adset, the new daily value must be at least 10% greater than the current amount already spent in the **SAME** day and the next day we can set any budget as long as it is > $1 and is at least twice our bid?

For example: if an ad set has a *$10* daily budget and has spent *$5* since the beginning of the day, the lowest new daily budget would be *$5.5*. The next day budget doesn’t depend on previous days budgets. Right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has updated the logic for lifetime_budget. [It](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3) now sates:

> An updated budget begins spending from zero (if there's a switch in budget types, the entire set spend to date is set to zero for the purposes of calculating the remaining budget).

Accordingly, if you update the daily budget to $20, it will spend 20 dollars for that day in addition to what it has already spent for the given day. From next day onwards it should work as $20 daily budget.

Comment: thanks! I'm adding the link to the [complete doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.3)

Comment: but this doesn't exactly answer to my question, about the minimum budget that I can set in the same day :)